# Docker 1.7.1: Is there a way to provide dynamic information to Dockerfile while building image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build an image on Bamboo agent where http_proxy is dynamically set by an administrator and keeps changing.

I need to provide `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade -y` in Dockerfile which in turn requires access to this dynamically set corporate http_proxy

Any pointers on how to provide this to `docker build` / Dockerfile?

Basically, I am looking for an option like --build-arg that was introduced in latest docker version.

PS: Upgrading docker version is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that works on 1.7.1 would be to create a file like `env`:

```
export http_proxy=<your-proxy>
export https_proxy=<your-proxy>
```

Then in your Dockerfile `COPY` it in and then `source` it before your apt commands in the `RUN` instruction something like:

```
# Dockerfile
...
COPY env /scripts/
RUN source /scripts/env && \
    apt-get update
...
```

Then you just change the proxy values in the `env` file prior to build. Could do this manually or create a hook type script to do it. The obvious massive downside of this is that you're busting your build cache all the time copying the new file in. I don't see any other options because of your (really) old Docker version though.

Comment: Thank you @johnharris85. That worked! Unfortunately, the bamboo version upgrade is not in my hands and hence had to look for workarounds.

Comment: Sure. Feel free to accept / upvote if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Please do upvote the question if you felt it was easy in understanding :)